# Remove image background in website?

Tags: html, css, image

How do I make the background in an image transparent?  Most of my images have a white background. When I use them in my website with my body background color black it looks awkward.

I have unsuccessfully tried using [Fireworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Fireworks) magic wand tool to remove the white background.  I have also applied the CSS transparent property but it does not work for me either.

What is the best means of making the background color of an image transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use photoshop to remove the background and save it as .png

remove it like this: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-remove-image-background-in-photoshop-tutorial/

or using magic eraser.

good luck!

Answer (score 5):

#### What image format you should use

You should use PNG pictures with alpha channel, so called RGBA image.

Save your work as PNG and make sure it is saved with RGBA colors.

[Wikipedia.org, Portable Network Graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)

#### How to, using GIMP (should be similar with photoshop)

- Open your picture file with [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/).
- If your picture layer does not contain alpha channel add it by right clicking on layer and selecting *"Add Alpha Channel"*.
- Use *"Fuzzy Select"*, *"Select By Color"* or *"Scissors Select"* tool to select backround area.
- Hit delete.
- Save results as [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) format with RGBA colors.

It should look something like this after you're done with it:

[image: Background cleared out]

#### Few notes

- Play around with mentioned selection tools to learn which one to use in which situation.
- Also pay attention to tool settings especially with fuzzy and color selection tools.
- If your picture contains blurred transitions between subject and backround, you should try to make them so with final picture too. You could use

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to alter the actual image to make it transparent -- sounds like it might not be?  Often images themselves have white backgrounds, so laying these on top of anything might look odd.  You can take the image and remove the white in it and save it as a transparent image, then try again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in photoshop with background eraser tool

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have Photoshop - the easiest way to do it is with MS Word (2010).

1. Change a background of your page to black (Page Layout --> Page Color --> Set to the color of your website)
2. Insert --> Picture
3. Once your have inserted pickture, go to **Picture Tools** and find **Background Removal** tool  under **Picture Tools**.
4. Select area you want to remove and click "Remove" and then "Done"

Comment: friends dont let friends use ms word. GIMP FTW!

Comment: +1, Don't know why this has been downvoted. It's a valid solution and doesn't require a very expensive specialist editing tool.

Answer (score 0):

use photoshop , select unwanted portion of image and then save it as png, But it'll may not work in IE, Use PNG Fix More details http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/

Answer (score 0):

To remove the background of the images, you can use [This Website](https://www.remove.bg/). It is very easy.

Steps:

1. Go to the link
2. Select the photo or enter the URL
   [image]
3. Download the image.
   [image]